# Why doesn't django-enumfield work as advertised in the manual?

Tags: python, django

I am am following [**these instructions**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-enumfield/1.0.1) exactly to install and run django-enumfields. But as you can see below, it is not working. Has anyone else gotten this module to work?

```
$ sudo pip install django-enumfield
  Downloading/unpacking django-enumfield
  Downloading django-enumfield-1.0.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/django-enumfield/setup.py) egg_info for package django-enumfield

Installing collected packages: django-enumfield
  Running setup.py install for django-enumfield

Successfully installed django-enumfield
Cleaning up...


$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


>>> from django_enumfield import enum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django_enumfield


>>> from django-enumfield import enum
File "<stdin>", line 1
from django-enumfield import enum
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Tested it and it works here, and you haven't got any spelling mistakes. Try rebooting?

Comment: Tested and works for me. Is your PYTHONPATH set up correctly? Could this be some environment issue? Have you tried doing the install in a new virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @SaeX.
My $PYTHONPATH was not set correctly. 
Oops.